# Trying to receive and save image from an HTTP request on Android (Wunderground)

Tags: android, http, httpwebrequest, wunderground

first let me say that I am new to Android, and specifically to http-related things.
This question is pertaining to development on the Android platform.

Ok, here is what I am trying to do.
Wunderground has an "api" that lets me send a request to a url. It looks like this:

```
http://api.wunderground.com/api/***API KEY HERE***/radar/image.gif?centerlat=38&centerlon=-96.4&radius=100&width=280&height=280&newmaps=1
```

I have been crawling the web trying to find the easiest way to send this request, then somehow parse the response and save the image. I then want to overlay the radar image onto Google Maps using MapView. I figured out the overlay part after some trial and error. But this Http stuff is getting the best of me.

I know that it would be best to not have this code run in my UI thread, but I am unsure what that means as well as how to implement it.

Also, I assume the image will have to be stored before I can use it? I want to add it to my MapOverlays, which I would do like this:

```
OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(myGeoPoint, "Hi!", "Here I am!");
itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
```

One last thing, if anyone has any ideas on how to make sure my radar overlay and my google maps view lines up, that would be great to hear!

Thank you for taking the time to read my question. I am sorry if I somehow missed something on the forum that already answers my question. But I couldn't find what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

For Image Download ... Check this http://code.google.com/p/android-imagedownloader/

Regarding the maps view check this to start up with.....

[Current position on google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141388/current-position-on-google-maps)